# Strange behaviour in nightwatch text assertion

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

I am pretty new to nightwatchjs and encountering a strange behaviour when I tried to assert simple text in a single dom

[image]

Same assertion method and one works but another doesn't

```
// This works
client.expect.element('#MenuToggle').text.to.contain('Menu'); 

// This doesn't work and it always returns empty "" string
client.expect.element('#BackToMain').text.to.contain('Back to main');
```

Answer (score 0):

The code given in your question is correct and should work... To help you with debugging, please try to run the following minimal working example:

**HTML** (*index.html*)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Nightwatch</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="#" class="site-header__menu" id="MenuToggle">Menu</a>
  <a href="#" class="site-header__back-to-main" id="BackToMain">Back to main</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript** (*test.js*)

```
module.exports = {
  'Test': function (browser) {
    browser.url('http://localhost:8000/index.html'); // Change this if needed
    browser.expect.element('#MenuToggle').text.to.contain('Menu');
    browser.expect.element('#BackToMain').text.to.contain('Back to main');
    browser.end();
  }
};
```

**Command**

```
nightwatch -t tests/test.js
```

If it does not work:

1. Check if your environment is OK (it works with **Node v7.7.4** + **Nightwatch v0.9.14**).
2. Edit your question to add more code.